# Linear Mixed Model: Specification of matrices

Tags: generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures, panel-data, statistical-power

I would like to conduct a power analysis for a linear mixed model with fixed effects for Treatment (Two levels) and Time (four time points: pre, mid, post treatment, 3 months post treatment) and correlated random effects for children (intercepts and slopes). I am using the following code in R using the `lmer` function:

```r
library(lme4)
expdat <- expand.grid(kid = factor(1:500), Time = factor(1:4), 
                      Treat = c("XTx", "BAU"))
expdat$obs <- factor(seq(nrow(expdat)))

set.seed(101)
nsim <- 20
beta <- c(100, -7, 8, 15, 20, 0, 0, 0)
theta <- c(15.000000, 7.500000, 7.500000, 7.500000, 12.990381, 
           4.330127, 4.330127, 12.247449, 3.061862, 11.858541)
ss <- simulate(~Treat*Time + (1+Time | kid), nsim = nsim, 
                family = gaussian, weights = rep(25, 
    nrow(expdat)), newdata = expdat, 
newparams = list(theta = theta, beta = beta, sigma = 1))
expdat$Outcome <- ss[, 1]
fit1 <- lmer(Outcome ~ Treat*Time + (1+Time | kid), data = expdat)
```

This is a repeated measurement design where each person is measured four times. To simulate the data assuming random intercepts and random slopes and their correlations, shouldn't I specify the covariance matrix for the random effects? How would one do that in R?